# Multiple filter for 1 condition in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count how many type that have a `c` and `approved` status from the table below.

```
type   status_1  status_2   status_3    status_4     status_5    status_6
1         a      revised      c         approved       null       null
2         a      approved     c         approved       null       null
3         b      rejected     a         revised         c        approved       
4         a      rejected     b         rejected        c        approved_with_comment
```

The status column always comes in pairs.  So, `status_1` paired with `status_2`, `status_3` paired with `status_4`,  `status_5` with `status_6`.
I want to create a logic with query that state: number of type that has been `c` and `approved`.

```
The query is supposed to express:
status_1 = c and status_2 = approved
status_3 = c and status_4 = approved
status_5 = c and status_6 = approved
```

With the table above, the query should result 3 type.

Can somebody help on how I write the query in order to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data model, so you don't have such repeated data.  There should be separate rows in a separate table rather than repeated columns.

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select count(*)
from t
where ( 'c', 'approved') in ( (status_1, status_2), (status_3, status_4), (status_5, status_6) );
```

Comment: thankyou! do you have any idea on how should I improve my data model to be more efficient?

Comment: @nomnom3214 . . . Have another table with type/status combinations -- or the "statuses" look like they come in pairs, so it might be type/status/status combinations.